# Content Security Policy with JQGrid

Tags: jqgrid, content-security-policy

I am using JQGrid extensively in my code base. Now that I have added Content Security Policy `default-src 'self'`, none of my grids are loading.

If I change it to `default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'`, the grids start loading again.

Is there any mechanism by which I can tweak JQGrid to play nice with CSP without adding the `unsafe-inline` directive?

Comment: Please specify always **the version** of jqGrid, which you use (can use) and **the fork** ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7). A part of problem in usage of Content Security Policy in free jqGrid fork are described in [the issue](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/issues/403) and are fixed in the latest versions of free jqGrid. If you use free jqGrid and still have problems, please provide the demo, which reproduce the problem.

Comment: I am using jqGrid 4.15.6-pre. Not sure if it's the latest version. Anyway, I will check the free jqGrid link you shared and try to see if it works alright.

Comment: It's the katest version. What kind of grid you use (simple grid, data grouping, TreeGrid and so on)? Which formatters you use? Could you include the exact `meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"`, which you use? The best would be if you post the link to the demo, which reproduces the problem.